# How to remove the Extra Dot in SliderLayout?

Tags: android

Please Find the Image below:

[image: Please Find the Image HERE]

> I am using Slider Layout Library in my app. It's a single Image slider.

```
implementation 'com.daimajia.slider:library:1.1.5@aar'
```

> How can I remove the Dot from the Slider as shown in IMAGE ABOVE?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can remove an indicator from a slider.

there is `setIndicatorVisibility` property available. using this property you can set the visibility of indicators.

for more detail, you can [visi](https://github.com/daimajia/AndroidImageSlider/wiki/Start-Using)t it.

Answer (score 0):

To Remove this dot (Indicator) you can use

```
slider.setIndicatorVisibility(PagerIndicator.IndicatorVisibility.Invisible);
```

To show you can use

```
slider.setIndicatorVisibility(PagerIndicator.IndicatorVisibility.Visible);
```